# load_plugin_text_domain() never works

Tags: textdomain

This code never works:

```
function i18n_load_plugin_textdomain() {
    $path = '[DIR]/wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/languages/my-plugin-de_DE.mo';     
    load_plugin_textdomain( 'my-plugin', false, $path);
}
add_action('plugins_loaded', 'i18n_load_plugin_textdomain');
```

I also tried 'init' instead of 'plugins_loaded' hook.

I tested $path with this different values (strings!) - no one worked. load_plugin_textdomain() returned always false.

```
$path = '[URL]/wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/languages/my-plugin-de_DE.mo';
$path = '[DIR]\wp-content\plugins\my-plugin/languages/my-plugin-de_DE.mo';
$path = 'languages/my-plugin-de_DE.mo';
$path = '/languages/my-plugin-de_DE.mo';
$path = '/languages/';
$path = '/languages';
$path = 'languages';
$path = '/';
$path = '';
```

But this works:

```
function i18n_load_textdomain() {
    $mofile = '[DIR]/wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/languages/my-plugin-de_DE.mo';
    load_textdomain( 'my-plugin', $mofile);
}
add_action('plugins_loaded', 'i18n_load_textdomain');
```

Can anyone tell me WHY?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why did u write `$path:` and not `$path=` in your first function code?

Wait forget it, you have to privde the relative path, you're providing the full path.. When using load_plugin_textdomain, you gotta use your plugin folder + your language files folder only; so if your language files are inside wp-content/plugins/your-plugin/languages, use

```
load_plugin_textdomain( 'your-plugin', false, 'your-plugin/languages' );
```

When I do it like this with my plugins translations always work. And I remember that whenever translations of my plugins didn't work, the wrong path was the problem in most of the cases.

Comment: sorry was only a write error in this post not in my php code, it is now corrected.

Comment: load_plugin_textdomain( 'my-plugin', false, $path); The second param is false and that is correct.

Comment: Thank you - Can't believe it, I think, I tried this too, perhaps I have overlooked it. But this works indeed:
$path = 'my-plugin/languages';

Comment: Ur welcome buddy!